# Wiki tutorials indexing with FullSearchWithDescriptionsCS macro

Tags: ros, tutorial, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m creating documentation and tutorials for siemens_cp1616 package (GSoC project). Currently I have 7 tutorial pages that were created in almost random order. I use FullSearchWithDescriptionsCS macro to search and list all tutorials on siemens_cp1616/Tutorials page. It works, it generates the list but I would like to change the order of the list to be more logical and start with introduction, not with runtime tutorial. Is it possible to re-define order in tutorial indexing? Or am I missing some option on the wiki page or header?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215560/wiki-tutorials-indexing-with-fullsearchwithdescriptionscs-macro/) by [Frantisek.Durovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/19768/frantisek.durovsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend using the TutorialChain macro:

http://wiki.ros.org/WikiMacros#TutorialChain

This macro was designed to replace the full search one, since that macro makes the wiki really slow. Even if there is not a logical order to your tutorials, just order them arbitrarily but statically so that the wiki loads faster.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Frantisek.Durovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/19768/frantisek.durovsky/) on 2015-08-11**:
Thanks Wiliam, Tutorial Chain works great